# Operations upon a sorted sequence not honoring the sort order

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, saxon

I'm having trouble understanding why XSLT (Saxon 9.1 and 9.5) is working the way it does when using a variable containing a sorted sequence.

Here is the output of my program with my three questions embedded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
The following sequence is unsorted...

  sequence $list                        = (<contribution e="4"/><contribution e="1"/><contribution e="2"/><contribution e="8"/>)

It is, as I expected, in document order.

The following sequence is explicitly sorted...

  sequence $sorted-list                 = (<contribution e="8"/><contribution e="4"/><contribution e="2"/><contribution e="1"/>)

It is, as I expected, sorted in descending numerical @e order.

In the following output, I expect for the @e values from $list to be in document order,
and for the @e values from $sorted-list to be in descending numerical order...

  value-of $list/@e                     = (4 1 2 8)
  value-of $sorted-list/@e              = (4 1 2 8)

But both are in document order.

Specifically, the $sorted-list/@e values are NOT listed in descending numerical @e order.
(Question 1: ...By the way, why can't I use 'xsl:sequence select="$list/@e"' here?)

Next, here's the real work that I'm interested in. It is a function that computes a running
subtotal of the elements passed in. Order is critical here. I expect for my sorted list to provide
@e values to the function in the order that I explicitly put them in the definition of $sorted-list.
So, in the following call, I send in the sequence that I think SHOULD have been sorted...

  sequence f($sorted-list/@e)           = (0 4 5 7 15)

But my result set is a list of running subtotals that are obviously not correctly ordered.
Question 2: Is this a bug, or evidence of a gap in my comprehension?

In the following call, I send a sequence that's explicitly ordered...

  sequence f(for...$sorted-list[$i]/@e) = (0 8 12 14 15)

...and I receive the sequence I need. I can use this as a workaround.

Question 3: Why is it that I must explicitly [re-]sort the $sorted-list sequence as I pass it to util:f()?
```

Here's my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <contribution e="4"/>
    <contribution e="1"/>
    <contribution e="2"/>
    <contribution e="8"/>
</root>
```

...And my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:util="http://www.method-r.com/util"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs util"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
The following sequence is unsorted...

  sequence $list                        = (<xsl:sequence select="$list"/>)

It is, as I expected, in document order.

The following sequence is explicitly sorted...

  sequence $sorted-list                 = (<xsl:sequence select="$sorted-list"/>)

It is, as I expected, sorted in descending numerical @e order.

In the following output, I expect for the @e values from $list to be in document order,
and for the @e values from $sorted-list to be in descending numerical order...

  value-of $list/@e                     = (<xsl:value-of select="$list/@e"/>)
  value-of $sorted-list/@e              = (<xsl:value-of select="$sorted-list/@e"/>)

But both are in document order.

Specifically, the $sorted-list/@e values are NOT listed in descending numerical @e order.
(Question 1: ...By the way, why can't I use 'xsl:sequence select="$list/@e"' here?)

Next, here's the real work that I'm interested in. It is a function that computes a running
subtotal of the elements passed in. Order is critical here. I expect for my sorted list to provide
@e values to the function in the order that I explicitly put them in the definition of $sorted-list.
So, in the following call, I send in the sequence that I think SHOULD have been sorted...

  sequence f($sorted-list/@e)           = (<xsl:sequence select="util:f(0, $sorted-list/@e)"/>)

But my result set is a list of running subtotals that are obviously not correctly ordered.
Question 2: Is this a bug, or evidence of a gap in my comprehension?

In the following call, I send a sequence that's explicitly ordered...

  sequence f(for...$sorted-list[$i]/@e) = (<xsl:sequence select="util:f(0, for $i in 1 to count($sorted-list) return $sorted-list[$i]/@e)"/>)

...and I receive the sequence I need. I can use this as a workaround.

Question 3: Why is it that I must explicitly [re-]sort the $sorted-list sequence as I pass it to util:f()?

<xsl:text/>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:variable name="list" as="element()*" select="//contribution"/>

    <xsl:variable name="sorted-list" as="element()*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$list">
            <xsl:sort select="number(@e)" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>



    <xsl:function name="util:f" as="xs:double*">
        <xsl:param name="sum0" as="xs:double"/>
        <xsl:param name="list" as="xs:double*"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="util:cumulative-list-2((), $list)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="util:cumulative-list-2" as="xs:double*">
        <xsl:param name="list" as="xs:double*"/>
        <xsl:param name="list-remainder" as="xs:double*"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(exists($list-remainder))">
                <xsl:sequence select="$list"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="util:cumulative-list-2(
                    if (empty($list)) then
                    (0, $list-remainder[1])
                    else 
                    ($list, $list[last()] + $list-remainder[1]),
                    remove($list-remainder, 1)
                    )"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function> 


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have to admit this is quite unexpected behavior. Maybe is has to do with the fact that according to the documentation (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.5/xsl-elements.html#xsl:sequence) a sequence _does not create a copy_. Probably, only @MichaelKay can help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a step doing `$sorted-list/@e` the `/@e` will select all `@e` attributes and sort in document order thus if you have your sorted sequence and want to output the `@e` attributes in the order of the sequence have you can't use `$sorted-list/@e`, instead you have to use `for $item in $sorted-list return $item/@e`.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-path-expressions which says:

> Each operation E1/E2 is evaluated as follows: ... If every evaluation
>   of E2 returns a (possibly empty) sequence of nodes, these sequences
>   are combined, and duplicate nodes are eliminated based on node
>   identity. The resulting node sequence is returned in document order.

If you use the commercial editions of Saxon 9.5 then you should also be able to make use of http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator and `$sorted-list ! @e` to preserve the order.

Comment: Brilliant; thank you, Martin. So, picking up on your lead, I tried the expression $sorted-list/number(@e) and got the sorted order that I desired. Presumably, this is because number(@e) is an atomic value, which invokes item #2 of the  http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-path-expressions citation you gave me, which says: "If every evaluation of E2 returns a (possibly empty) sequence of atomic values, these sequences are concatenated, in order, and returned."

Comment: @CaryMillsap, yes, using an expression (on the right hand side of `/`) which returns atomic values is another option.

Comment: Should probably also mention the approach which some people would consider canonical, of using `for $x in $sorted-list return $x/@e`

Comment: @MichaelKay, it's in there, the first paragraph ends with "instead you have to use `for $item in $sorted-list return $item/@e`".

Comment: Picking up on @MichaelKay's tactful “which some people would consider canonical,” I'm going to go with the `for $x in $sorted-list return $x/@e`, which will be more explicit and less tricky to understand when I revisit this code in the future. I'm hopeful that when I profile my code, there won't be a significant runtime performance difference between the `for $x` method and the `number(@e)` method.

Comment: By the way, @MichaelKay explains this whole phenomenon clearly in “XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 4.ed” on page 602.